# Rails 4 full page caching is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Rails4 full page caching is removed and extracted as gem and I am using that gem called 'actionpack-page_caching', but it is not working. It is throwing undefined method `caches_page' for controller class. I tried a lot to debug the issue but no relevant documentation for the same. Please help me out with the solutions.

Answer (score 8):

Even though your bundle command says you have those 2 gems installed

```
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
```

Try to delete the `Gemfile.lock` file and run the `bundle`command again.
And my output on the second run was correct:

```
Installing actionpack-action_caching (1.1.0)
Installing actionpack-page_caching (1.0.2)
```

And I was able to use `caches_page`.